# Need help with Jquery selectors on drupal

Tags: php, jquery, drupal

I'm having problem with Jquery on Drupal.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve, I needed to get the `html()` of my primary link. For example one of my primary link have a sub menus/child menus. I need to get those child menus using Jquery. My problem is I can't retrive it using `$("#menuID").html()`, it always returns null. It seems that the page was not yet fully loaded when the function was called. I placed it inside `$(document).ready()` but still won't work.

file.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){      
       console.log($('#id-of-the-menu').html());

    });
```

I called file.js on page.tpl.php

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your prose you mention `$("#menuID").html("")`, in the example `$('#id-of-the-menu').html()`. Which one do you use?

Comment: In addition to @AndreKR's question, what does the markup for this element look like?

Comment: Anyway, `$("#menuID").html("")` won't return anything. It'll change `#menuID`'s content.

Comment: @Chouchenos Though it wouldn't return null, but the jQuery object...

Comment: Sorry about it guys- I was using this $('#id-of-the-menu').html() not this $("#menuID").html("")

Comment: @lonesomeday : true as we can see in the manual _.html( htmlString ) Returns: jQuery_, I knew it but misspelled here. I should have had "as a string" in my previous comment as he wanted the result to be (apparently).

Comment: @samer : I can't believe the `id` of the element is named `#id-of-the-menu` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call in your page.tpl.php the file.js after the "`<?php print $scripts ?>`"-tag in the head.

Also if there is more javascript action going on (collapsing menus, ...), look at the source of the page to see if there is inline-javascript and if so, even call your file.js at the bottom of page.tpl.php .

It could be the menu hasn't loaded because a module is preventing it to load in a normal way (but then we'll need more info on the modules you use).